# The Flutter SDK is installed in a protected folder and may not function correctly

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

**The Flutter SDK is installed in a protected folder and may not function correctly.Please move the SDK to a location that is user-writable without Administration permissions and restart.**

Above warning pops up when i open the VSCode even though i am  running it as administrator.
My flutter sdk resides in c:\program files\flutter

And when I try to run any flutter command from either vscode terminal or cmd(run as admin) it gives below error:

````
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: OS Error: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.
, errno = 10057, address = 169.254.169.254, port = 49839
#0      AzureDetector.isRunningOnAzure (package:flutter_tools/src/base/bot_detector.dart:91:41)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BotDetector.isRunningOnBot (package:flutter_tools/src/base/bot_detector.dart:66:31)
#2      isRunningOnBot (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:77:48)
#3      run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:38:36)
#4      main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:67:9)
#5      main (file:///C:/Program%20Files/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#6      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program files folder is protected in windows. you should not install flutter there. move it to another directory like `c:\src\flutter` and then go to Environment variables add the new directory's bin folder to path.

Answer (score 0):

The **initial warning** about protected folder went away **thanks to the accepted answer**. But was still getting the **error on running any flutter commands**. My problem solved when i **upgraded the flutter version** and now i can run any command.